# +? sign does still works in a greedy manner

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

when I run python commands as bellow :

```
z='From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008'
print(re.findall('\S+@\S+',z))
```

I get

```
['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za']
```

And when I run it again adding `?` as :

```
z='From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008'
print(re.findall('\S+@\S+?',z))
```

I get

```
['stephen.marquard@u']
```

Now, I want to print out `['d@uct.ac.za']` so I ran :

```
z='From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008'
print(re.findall('\S+?@\S+',z))
```

However, I received :

```
['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za']
```

I thought I would receive `['d@uct.ac.za']` since `?` makes `+` ungreedy.
Why am I wrong?

Comment: Remember, regex matching is done from left to right, and is always "greedy" (i.e., in the sense that it will find the _first_ match satisfying the expression, not the last). Your regex actually needs modification to something like `re.findall(r'\S@\S+',z)`

Comment: So, the matching starts from s in stephen right? Thank you very much. @coldspeed

Comment: Correct, that's how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
re.findall('\S+?@\S+',z)
```

it starts from beginning trying to be as non-greedy as possible until it finds a `'@'` and then the remaining. `'\S+?@'` simply takes all characters from beginning till `'@'`.

In the case of `'\S+@\S+?'`, you don't give anything to the right of `?`, meaning it makes the regex more non-greedy - Takes exactly one.

Suppose, if you give like `'\S+?@\S+?\.'` (a dot after `?`), it follows the rule similar to the first scenario - tries to be as non-greedy as possible until it sees a `.` (dot).

Comment: Thank you very much. What does beginning mean in this case? Is it the beginning of the email address?

Comment: @SuminKim, yes. Beginning of the word (email) to be precise.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!